# Lenovo 900: mouse freeze requently

Tags: mouse, kde, lenovo

I have a lenovo 900 with kde installed. I recently updated from kde 16.04 to 17.04. Now my mouse freeze frequently. When this occurs, I can't move the mouse and I can click. After restart, my mouse still don't work. For it to work, I must shutdown my system and start with the power button. I am trying to understand what is going on but I don't know where to start. Have you had this issue? how to solve it?

Thanks.